# Single Precision a x plus y (SAXPY) terminology

Tags: linear-solver, complexity, numerics, precision

I've been reading books which refers to vector update operations of the form: y := y + a*x, where y and x are vector variables and a is a scalar as SAXPY. I understand a*x plus y part, but why "single precision"?

I'm seeing it in the context of complexity estimates of iterative linear solvers, where I assume that most variables (the vectors and matrices) are double precision, not single. But vector updates are still described as SAXPY.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is before my time, but the old [Cray Single Precision](https://web.archive.org/web/20160915040442/https://www.cisl.ucar.edu/zine/96/fall/articles/4.ieee.formats.html) was 64-bit, and so the name stuck for supercomputer users who got used to it. "Sax pee" is just more natural to say than "Dax pee", besides.

Comment: Wow, really? To me, SAXPY really just means 32-bit `float` or `REAL*4` arithmetic, and DAXPY means 64-bit `double` or `REAL*8`. In fact, I hear people use the term DAXPY far more often than SAXPY these days, and that makes sense because nobody still uses single precision.

Comment: Me, too, until I remembered that Cray had it's own "float" type. We're too young, @WolfgangBangerth!

Comment: Cray's in the last millennium also had haxpy, the h standing for "half" - this was the 32 bit routine

Answer (score -1):

Does the book mention "single precision" explicitly, or is that your reading for the abbreviation? Maybe they intend the S to stand for "scalar", to make clear that the operation is $y\gets \alpha x+y$ and not $y \gets Ax+y$ for a matrix $A$.

Comment: In the BLAS library the naming convention is that the first letter (s, d, c, or z) denotes the precision.  Saxpy is a single precision routine.